# Item deleting not firing from selecting item

Tags: 2013, event-receivers

Item Deleting event receiver is getting fired when i delete a document from edit form and deleting from Ribbon . But item deleting is not getting fired when i select the list item and try deleting from the call out options ?

Comment: Hi! I cannot reproduce your issue in my environment. Could you please add some more details about your environment / code? Which version of SharePoint do you use (including language and patch level)? Is it a dev. environment (where you can debug your code) or production? Is it a document library or a list (there are known differences between them)? Are you sure it is not invoked, or you simply don't see the effect you expect? I wrote a post about such problem five years ago (see https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/my-event-receiver-doesnt-fire/), it might help you to track down the issue.

Comment: This is in all environments . The code doesnt hit the debugger in my dev when i use callout delete .

Comment: Which version of SharePoint do you use? 2013? Is it a document library or a list? Could you add an extra line at the entry point of the event receiver just to log the event into the ULS logs, comment out any other code in the method, and test it in the dev. environment? Simply that the debugger does not catch the event does not mean for sure, that the event has not been triggered. The process responsible for the event handling (like IIS) may crash as well before handling the event (IISRESET?), see https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/understanding-sharepoint-event-receivers/

Comment: I use sp2013 . Its a document library with only major versions . i can try what u suggested , thx

Comment: I was able to track the issue . Can you provide this as answer , i can make it resolved

Comment: I was redirecting to the different page from event handler where there is a HttpContext . The Context is null all time and gets you to catch expection . But now the issue is its not redirecting to page and gets stuck in owssvr .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please add some more details about your environment / code?

- Which version of SharePoint do you use (including language and patch level)?
- Is it a dev. environment (where you can debug your code) or production?
- Is it a document library or a list (there are known differences between them)? - Are you sure it is not invoked, or you simply don't see the effect you expect?

I wrote a post about such problem five years ago (see [this post](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/my-event-receiver-doesnt-fire/)), it might help you to track down the issue.

Could you add an extra line at the entry point of the event receiver just to log the event into the ULS logs, comment out any other code in the method, and test it in the dev. environment?

Simply that the debugger does not catch the event does not mean for sure, that the event has not been triggered. The process responsible for the event handling (like IIS) may crash as well before handling the event (`IISRESET`?), see the [post of Hristo Pavlov](https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/understanding-sharepoint-event-receivers/).

Answer (score 0):

got the same error a couple of months ago. It ended up with

- install SharePoint Manager 2013 on SP Server
- check whether the event receiver is bound to the list with **the current version** / bound correctly

In our case the receiver was bound but with a corrupt version! So obviously the event was firing but ended in nirvana without any effect. We **deleted the deployed and bound event receiver by SharePoint Manager** and deployed the solution again. After that the event was firing.
By the way: before we came to this solution some iisreset seemed to help but only up to the point we deployed a newer version...

Comment: The tool I mentioned in my original comments above (https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/my-event-receiver-doesnt-fire/) helps to detect such orphaned event reciever registrations either.

Comment: ok, I didn't notice that, thanks - always good to have tool options ;)